eclipse cannot complete the installation of updates
installed eclipse 2024-03 and tried to install the updates for the first time. But it will not complete because of the following error:
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  Software being installed: Wild Web Developer XML tools 1.3.4.202405270639 (org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.xml.feature.feature.group 1.3.4.202405270639)
  Software currently installed: JustJ Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete 17.0.11.v20240426-1830 (org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.feature.group 17.0.11.v20240426-1830)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JustJ Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete 17.0.11.v20240426-1830 (org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full 17.0.11.v20240426-1830)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; a.jre.javase 0.0.0, min=0, max=0, filter=(!(org.eclipse.justj.buildtime=true))
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JustJ Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete 17.0.11.v20240426-1830 (org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.feature.group 17.0.11.v20240426-1830)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full [17.0.11.v20240426-1830,17.0.11.v20240426-1830]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: XML support using Language Server 1.3.4.202405270639 (org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.xml 1.3.4.202405270639)
    To: osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=21))
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Wild Web Developer XML tools 1.3.4.202405270639 (org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.xml.feature.feature.group 1.3.4.202405270639)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.xml [1.3.4.202405270639,1.3.4.202405270639]

I can only press cancel. What is missing? And why he didnt correct it automatically. I installed Eclipse 2024-03 Java Edition and installed PDT on top.

The error message states that the Wild Web Developer XML Tools require a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) of version 21, but your current JRE is version 17.0.11. Mismatching this version causes the installation to fail because the dependency cannot be provided.
Try installing the appropriate version from here: https://adoptium.net/
and reconfigure it in eclipse, and then try to reinstall. That should help

Eclipse 2024-06 (or at least some parts of it like Eclipse Wild Web Developer) requires Java 21 to run.
See details and what to do: https://www.eclipse.org/setups/sponsor/?campaign=2024-06
